# Does a Pakistani need a visa to stopover in Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, uae, stopovers

I am a Pakistani passport holder and I am flying on Dubai Airlines from Seoul, South Korea to Lahore, Pakistan. I have a stopover in Dubai, staying for 3 days; I have hotel reservations.

Do I get a transit visa on arrival? How much does it cost?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PK&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=AE&selTrans=United%20Arab%20Emirates&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers can obtain a transit visa
>   at Dubai (DXB) for a maximum of 96 hours. The passenger must:
>
> - transit for at least 8 hours; and
> - have onward ticket to a third country; and
> - have a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the
>     arrival date. 
>     Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package
>     together with hotel accommodation and airport transfer. (SEE
>     NOTE 41363)
>     NOTE 41363: This does not apply to nationals of
>     Afghanistan, Iraq, Niger, Somalia and Yemen.

You are not in the list of excluded nationalities. So if you have booked a transit package with a hotel and airport transfer, you can get the visa on arrival.

If you're unsure of whether you've booked a transit package, ask Flydubai or your Hotel, who might be able to help.